# Why is my function to print to pdf using selenium chromedriver creating whitespace in the header and footer?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a project to script an annual report from data straight through to pdf creation. It mostly functions but currently I have to manually print to pdf for each page in chrome as the function I have created to do this seems to be creating additional whitespace in the header and footer.

The pages print mostly OK (still have to specifically only select page 1) if I do this manually but If I use my function they are printed with additional header and footer whitespace. The function is as below and the full script etc. can be found on github at [https://github.com/SC-TPP/LGBF](https://stackoverflow.com) - issue is in the buld report.ipynb file in the savetopdf function and the lines commented out in the last cell.

```
def savetopdf (htmlpath,pdfpath) :
    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    filepath = os.path.abspath(htmlpath)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
    
    print_settings = {
        "recentDestinations": [{
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": "",
        }],
        "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
        "version": 2,
        "isHeaderFooterEnabled": False,
        "isLandscapeEnabled": True,
        
    }

    
    driver.get(f'file://{filepath}')
    pdf_data = driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.printToPDF", print_settings)
    driver.close()
    
    with open(f'{filepath}.pdf', "wb") as f:
        f.write(base64.b64decode(pdf_data['data']))
```

I have tried disabling header and footer, I have also attempted to set page sizing to the exact size specified in the css for the pages (this did nothing at all). Have read a number of posts on stack overflow and tried quite a few of the suggestions for similar posts to no avail.